# Как предоставить выбор только упомянутому пользователю в discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, input, бот, discord.py

Я написал код команды. По задумке после ее прописывания автором, **только** упомянутый пользователь сможет нажать на любую кнопку. Как это реализовать?
Я искал везде информацию, где только можно и принял решение задать вопрос на форуме.

Код:

```
@bot.command(aliases = ["свадьба", "жениться"])
async def предложение(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{member.mention}, тебе сделал предложение {ctx.author.mention}! Согласишься?"),
    components = [
      Button(style = ButtonStyle.green, label = "Согласиться"),
      Button(style = ButtonStyle.red, label = "Отказаться")
    ]
    )
    def check(m):
        return m.member.mention == ctx.member.mention
    responce = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=check)
    if responce.channel == ctx.channel:
        if responce.component.label == "Согласиться":
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f"**{ctx.author.name}** принял предложение **{member.name}** "))

    time.sleep(10)

    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f"**{ctx.author.name}** сыграли свадьбу с **{member.name}**!"))
    if responce.channel == ctx.channel:
        if responce.component.label == "Отказаться":
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f"**{member.name}** отказала **{ctx.author.name}** (обидно наверное) :raised_hand: "))
```

[image: пример работы кода]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать условие используя id автора и переменную с id упомянутого участника:

```
if ctx.author.id == "переменная с id упомянутого участника":
 print('Всё сработало')
else:
 print('Ошибка')
```

По идее, должно сработать.

Comment: Нужно конкретно заменить элементы проверки:

`def check(m):
        return m.member.mention == ctx.member.mention`

Они у меня ошибочные!

Comment: Я давно уже узнал ответ на этот вопрос и хочу поделиться им с другими! проверка должна быть вида **m.author.id == member.id**